# Not understanding how to use the return value of leaflet getCenter()

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to put a marker at the center point of these coordinates. After calculating the bounds, I use getCenter() to give me the coordinates. But it returns "LatLng(-93.20448, 38.902475)" in longitude latitude direction, so using them in the marker doesn't work. It needs lat lon. I realize I'm not understanding something but what is it that I don't understand.

```
var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[-94.778092, 39.967458], [-91.630869, 39.967458], [-91.630869, 37.8374921], [-94.778092, 37.8374921], [-94.778092, 39.967458]]);

var middle = bounds.getCenter(); alert(middle);   // LatLng(-93.20448, 38.902475)

var mk5 = new L.marker(new L.latLng( 38.902475, -93.20448  );
```

Comment: You are feeding the coordinates to the [`LatLngBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlngbounds) constructor in lng-lat order. The behaviour is as expected; this is just a case of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in%2C_garbage_out).

Comment: @IvanSanchez OMG!